# How can I add / remove a class from specific div on keyup of input using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want every time someone start typing text in the following input to add the class "hideme" to the div with id ( btn1) and when the field is cleaned/empty to remove the class "hideme" and display again the div.

As it is now if you try to type something in the input field it doesn't work properly.

Here's my code:

```js
$('#price').on('keyup', function(){
  $("#btn1").toggleClass('hideme', $('#price').val()==''); 
})
```

```css
#btn1 {
  background: #0088cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 8px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}

#price {
  height:43px;
  line-height:43px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#585858;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:1em;
}

.hideme {
  display:none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price"/> 
<div id="btn1">
  HEY I AM A NICE BUTTON
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have your logic back-to-front; you simply need to apply the class when the element is **not** empty (`!==`) instead of (`==`):

```js
$('#price').on('keyup', function() {
  $("#btn1").toggleClass('hideme', $('#price').val() !== '');
})
```

```css
#btn1 {
  background: #0088cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#price {
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #585858;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.hideme {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price" />
<div id="btn1">
  HEY I AM A NICE BUTTON
</div>
```

However, I would recommend making use of a simple `if` conditional which calls `removeClass()` if the `val()` is empty, or `else` calls `addClass()` if the value is populated.

This makes things much clearer, and can be seen in the following:

```js
$('#price').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#price').val() == '') {
    $("#btn1").removeClass('hideme');
  } else {
    $("#btn1").addClass('hideme');
  }
})
```

```css
#btn1 {
  background: #0088cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#price {
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #585858;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.hideme {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input autocomplete="off" id="price" placeholder="Enter Product Price" />
<div id="btn1">
  HEY I AM A NICE BUTTON
</div>
```